# c++ error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token

Tags: c++

Looked at every similar question on this compiler error.  The following minimized code reproduces the error and I cannot see what the issue is.  From reading here on SO, suspect it's the return type node* (being a struct) is invalid, but what else to specify as the return type? Thank you.

Header file:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

class double_clist {
  struct node {
     int info;
     struct node *next;
     struct node *prev;
  };
  node *start;
  node *last;
  int counter;

public:
  node *create_node(int);
  double_clist() {
     start = NULL;
     last = NULL;
  }
};
```

Implementation File:

```
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstdlib>

node* double_clist::create_node(int value) { // Error on this line.
    counter++;
    struct node *temp;
    temp = new(struct node);
    temp->info = value;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->prev = NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: `struct node *temp;` -> `node *temp;`, `new(struct node);` -> `new node;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When it reaches `node` here, it hasn't seen that it is inside `double_clist` yet. You need to also preface that with `double_clist::`.

```
double_clist::node* double_clist::create_node(int value) {
```